# What are those parts in peugeot 206 car?

Tags: part-identification, peugeot, peugeot-206

[image]

I want to know that what are those parts in peugeot 206 car ?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are the rotating joints holding the top of the McPherson struts which contain the shock absorber and spring for the front suspension allowing the steering to work.

Simply there is a bearing in there inside the rubber mount to dampen vibrations.